# err_too_many_redirects error if I access from Google

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website which I can reach writing its URL in the web explorer.  I can watch the website from there.  But, if I try to access the website from Google, a get an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

I have asked about this issue to my hosting provider.  They told me to add this code and to index the website to Google.  I have been waiting for a long time, and know my hosting provider just told me to ask to Stackoverflow  O.o

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So what is the host name google has indexed? The variant _with_ or _without_ "www." prefix?

Comment: is this same for different browsers? clear the cookies for the website + browser cache and try again

Comment: @arkascha  It is indexed with `www`

Comment: @UlugToprak It is the same with all browsers, even after clearing cache

Comment: Please tell us what redirection header is received by the browser.

Comment: @arkascha How can I check that?  The website is www.japanisyours.com

Comment: That redirection is not triggered by the dynamic configuration file you use, but by some framework, looks like an issue with the language switching.

Comment: The language switcher is managed by Joomla

Comment: @arkascha According to http://redirectdetective.com, it redirects like this: http://japanisyours.com --> https://japanisyours.com/ --> https://www.japanisyours.com/ --> https://www.japanisyours.com/index.php/es/

Comment: And then back again to `https://www.japanisyours.com/` ...